# MongoDb query OR clause having AND clause

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, mongodb-query

Would it be possible to write OR clause having AND clause inside.

For example I need to write a query on fields field1,field2,field3 and field4.

```
Query should be field1 or field2 or (filed3 and field4)
```

.

Can somebody help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, a simpler way would be:

```
{
   "$or" : [
             { "field1" : {"$gte" : 1} },
             { "field2" : {"$gte" : 1} },
             { "field3" : {"$gte" : 1}, "field4" : {"$gte" : 1} }
           ]
}
```

This is since the array elements in a single `$or` clause are actually `$and`. This would be more performant than using an explicit `$and` which is evaluated differently.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example for a query that will match if field1 > 1 OR field2 > 1 OR fields 3 and 4 are > 1:

```
{
   "$or" : [
             { "field1" : {"$gte" : 1} },
             { "field2" : {"$gte" : 1} },
             { 
               "$and" : [
                           { "field3" : {"$gte" : 1} },
                           { "field3" : {"$gte" : 1} }
                         ]
             }
           ]
}
```

Just switch the subqueries to your needs.